# splitting long literals in CSS source

Tags: css

Is there a way to split CSS literals on multiple lines ? I'm specifically interested in inlined images, for instance this rule is functional, but not easy to handle

```
.some-class { 
  background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN...etc...etc...gg==)
}
```

Comment: Nopes. Not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
.some-class { 
  background-image:url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo\
AAAAN...etc...etc...gg==')
}
```

surround width quotes than backslash before the break

i splitted the first line here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Xadvz/543/

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem to work on `http-requests`.

Otherwise use `\`.

**Example:**

```css
.background-image {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-size: cover;
}
.first-child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/image_\
    output/animals-q-c-100-100-3.jpg');
}

.last-child {
  /*Splitting long literals*/
  background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulr\
    SOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7');
```

```html
<div class="background-image first-child">
  <!-- Empty block -->
</div>

<div class="background-image last-child">
  <!-- Empty block -->
</div>
```

Comment: how it is different from my answer?

Comment: @holden While I was creating an example, you posted the same answer.